# Versioned deployment seems to be redirecting to HEAD deployment after OAuth login

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-oauth, add-on

I have a google workspace addon which is extending gmail and is using app script oauth to connect our own system, https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2.

Our system has a development environment and a live environment, each uses a different identity client id secret which need to be used when connecting to each. I have stored these as different project properites with the development properties being prefixed with 'dev-' and i have a function that looks like this:
[getScriptPropery function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOGKw.png). This function has a variable that should let me change the script properties I access.

I have then created a versioned deployment that uses the live project properties and have kept my HEAD deployment using the develpoment properties. My problem is that once someone tries to login on the versioned deployment they seem to be redirected back to the HEAD version of the code which is using development project properties, this then breaks the login attempt and gives the following error: [AppScript login error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbkVl.png)  I have tested this by adding logging that is only in the HEAD version of the getScriptProperty function and you can see the logs swap to using the development properties after redirecting from the login attempt, [Logging example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXckt.png).

Is there a better way to manage deployments/project properties to stop this from happening or have a just missed something with how they are meant to work?

Comment: Could it be a cache issue? Does this happen with any user login in from other machines as well?

Comment: @Jescanellas I thought this at first but can't seem to pin this down to a cache. This happens for all users and has happened on my pc as well as another.